# How does django know the version a project/app was created with

Tags: django

I've upgraded my project from django 1.6 to django 1.7.

#### After fixing the upgrade "errors" I was getting an odd warning message:

./manage.py check
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_6.W001) Some project unittests may not execute as expected.
    HINT: Django 1.6 introduced a new default test runner. It looks like this project was generated using Django 1.5 or earlier. You should ensure your tests are all running & behaving as expected. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#new-test-runner for more information.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

#### I found a "fix" for the removing the warning message; add the following into my settings.py:

TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'

### My question is

How does django know what version my project was created with?

For fun I created a new django project and app, ran the same command, and no warnings were generated.  I've searched through all the files in my project and the test project, I don't see a reference to django version anywhere.

Anyone know where django is getting the project's django version from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, it just guesses based on the changes they make in each version.

If you're doing something that was recommended or just the way it worked in an old version, and it's been changed in a new version, they tell you that it's changed (and in which version).

You probably don't get the warning in the new project because the new version set it up that way by default.

Check out these files for more info:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/checks/compatibility/django_1_6_0.py
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/checks/compatibility/django_1_7_0.py

Comment: Yep that was it.  It looks like the weight value inside django compat 1.6 being >= 6 causes the warning.  Nice find, thank you!